# java Constructor can not convert to scala

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

i know java Constructor convert  into  Scala code. but this is my project Generic class implementation. i am using hibernate ,spring in this project and i create genericDAO trait but can't create It's implementation or i can't convert this java constructor to scala

This are 2 variables

```
private Class<T> entityClass;

private String entityClassName;
```

This is GenericDAOImpl class code    here GenericDAOImpl is the constructor

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public GenericDAOImpl() {
            Type genericSuperclass;
            Class<?> parametrizedClass = getClass();
            do {
                genericSuperclass = parametrizedClass.getGenericSuperclass();
                if (genericSuperclass instanceof Class) {
                    parametrizedClass = (Class<?>) genericSuperclass;
                }
            } while (genericSuperclass != null
                    && !(genericSuperclass instanceof ParameterizedType));
            this.entityClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) genericSuperclass)
                    .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            if (entityClass != null) {
                entityClassName = entityClass.getSimpleName();
            }
        }
```

Thanks From Milano

**EDIT**

I tried this

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 def this(T,ID){
   var genericSuperclass:Type;
   var parametrizedClass:Class[?]=getClass
   do {
            genericSuperclass = parametrizedClass.getGenericSuperclass()
            if (genericSuperclass instanceof[Class]) {
                parametrizedClass = (Class<?>) genericSuperclass
            }
        } while (genericSuperclass != null
                && !(genericSuperclass instanceof [ParameterizedType]))
        this.entityClass = (Class[T]) ((ParameterizedType) genericSuperclass)
                .getActualTypeArguments()[0]
        if (entityClass != null) {
            entityClassName = entityClass.getSimpleName()
        }

 }


 And this got compilation Error
```

Comment: What have you got/tried so far?

Comment: @Tala i just edit the question

Comment: @Tala this got compilation Error

Comment: @milano: you should study scala a little before dealing with reflection or other complicated things. Your "tried" code is very far from valid scala code.

Comment: @senia i know am doing is not good but the situation is very critical so i must do this because of my job.. 
but i must study scala..thats sure and thanx for your helps..that's unforgettable..   :)

Comment: @milano: `s\Class[?]\Class[_]\ `, `s\instanceof[Class]\isInstanceOf[Class]\ `, `s\(Class<?>) genericSuperclass\genericSuperclass.asInstanceOf[Class[_]]\ `, `s\[0]\(0)\ `, remove `def this(T,ID){` (class body is construvtor), there is no `do{...} while` in scala, you should initialize even `var`s.

Comment: @senia Thanx..and def this(T,ID) what instead of this

Comment: @milano: `class GenericDAOImpl[T, ID]`

Comment: @senia I got here some compilation error
        genericSuperclass = parametrizedClass.getGenericSuperclass()
 if (genericSuperclass isInstanceOf[Class]) 
                                          /\  here is the error

Comment: @milano: `s\isInstanceOf[Class]\.isInstanceOf[Class[_]]\ `.

Comment: @senia okay..but in [Class[_]] at staring of here compilation error says          ')' expected but '[' found.

Comment: @milano, `.` before `isInstanceOf`

Comment: @milano - try and work it out for yourself. Look things up, think about it. At the moment senia is just rewriting your code and you're not learning anything.

Comment: @selig okay i know that.. this moment i must learn and thanx for your comments

Comment: @senia It's working and really thanx... And if you write answer  am  mark as answer and thanx for your help

Comment: @milano: this answer will help no one. I guess you should just delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see some problems with the Java to Scala conversion. Specifically I would replace Java's `instanceof` with

```
isInstanceOf[SomeClass]
```

Casts change from

```
(Class[T])
```

to

```
.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
```

Add the class bound `?` changes to `_` (I think)

Array indexes change from square brackets to round brackets e.g.

```
.getActualTypeArguments[0]
```

to

```
.getActualTypeArguments(0)
```

Applying these changes to the original Java I get

```
class GenericDAOImpl[T] {
var genericSuperclass: Type = null
var parametrizedClass: Class[_] = getClass()
do {
    genericSuperclass = parametrizedClass.getGenericSuperclass()
    if (genericSuperclass.isInstanceOf[Class])
        parametrizedClass = genericSuperclass.asInstanceOf[Class[_]]
} while (genericSuperclass != null
                && !(genericSuperclass.isInstanceOf[ParameterizedType]))
val entityClass = genericSuperclass.asInstanceOf[ParameterizedType]
                .getActualTypeArguments()(0).asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
val entityClassName =
  if (entityClass != null) 
      entityClass.getSimpleName()
  else
      null
```

but ... it doesn't make sense to me, I would need to see more of your original class to get it to work.